# What is "Ticino" in my Windows 7 Explorer context menu?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, context-menu

I noticed today that I have a new Explorer context menu item called "Ticino" when I right-click a file on Windows 7. What is it?

[image: "Ticino" item in Windows Explorer context menu]

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The "Ticino" item is added to the Windows Explorer context menu by early versions of [Visual Studio Code Preview](https://code.visualstudio.com/). It opens the selected file in Code for editing.

Previous versions of Code did not remove the item properly during uninstallation. According to the [Code FAQ](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/FAQ) Microsoft fixed the issue as of version 0.3.0.

> **Q: I uninstalled Visual Studio Code on my Windows machine. Why do I still see Code in my Windows Explorer context menu?**
>
> **A**: We fixed this in VS Code 0.3.0.

Previously you may have needed to manually remove the following registry keys:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Ticino
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\directory\background\shell\Ticino
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\directory\shell\Ticino
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\directory\background\shell\Ticino
```

Comment: it brings some HATE!

Comment: I downloaded, installed and uninstalled the latest version of VS Code and it is STILL there...

Comment: I removed this and it's gone: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\directory\background\shell\Ticino

Comment: @MattCanty This is obviously some strange usage of the word "fixed" that I wasn't previously aware of.  As I'd have it, fixed would mean "we've cleaned up the mess we left behind" not just "we've stopped making more mess". My mother would agree.

Comment: @MattCanty Your comment should be the answer! Your comment worked for me.

Answer (score 29):

Should you want to remove this (in case you uninstalled one of the early versions of VS Code and won't install a newer one) remove the "Ticino" folder from this regedit paths:

- `\HKEY_CLASS_ROOT\*\shell`
- `\HKEY_CLASS_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell`
- `\HKEY_CLASS_ROOT\Directory\shell`

Comment: Why do you suggest to delete the keys ? The user may need this program, and he didn't requested to get rid of this at all ! He just asked what this context menu item was !

Comment: I came here via Google looking at how to remove it, so this is a useful answer.